# cout does not produce output

Tags: c++, oop, io

So I am in a method of an object, but the cout statement produces no output at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

Object::Method()
{
    printf("why is the next line not printing? This one prints fine\n");

    std::cout << "This line should print second, but doesnt" << std::endl;

    printf("but this line prints fine like the first!\n");
}
```

the output is:

> why is the next line not printing? This one prints fine
>
> but this line prints fine like the first!

I can't seem to figure out why it will not print. `std::flush` has no effect either.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. Please try to come up with an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It's possible `std::cout` has been redirected to another output source other than console output.  I can't really think of any other explanation.

Comment: Which IDE you are using? As I think it is something related to that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stay with either `std::cout` (C++ streams) or C-style streams.  Mixing them may produce undefined behavior.

For example, they could have separate "buffering" channels.

Comment: Staying with just printf has allowed all my code to work. But I thought they were designed to work together? So I'll accept it for now.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet runs fine on my system, your problem is probably coming from some other part of your code that isn't listed here. 
Try to `fflush(stdout)` at the beginning of method and see if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately it had no effect :/